# How to use Python 3.x with pew environment instead of Python 2.7?

Tags: python, environment

When I check the Python version for pew, I found it was 2.7, but I would like to use version 3.5 or above. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Pew with its optional [Pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) support (or simply install `pythonz` if you already have `pew`):

```
pip install --user pew[pythonz]
```

Then you can [install other versions of Python easily](https://github.com/berdario/pew#install):

```
pew install 3.7.3
```

Then you can [create a new environment using that Python](https://github.com/berdario/pew#new):

```
pew new -p $(pew locate_python 3.7.3) myenv
```

Comment: ThanksI have installed pythonz using :
pip install pew[pythonz] --user

And then I followed your steps!

Comment: Not working. Pythonz apparently isn't installed with Pew and I can't install it with `pip install pew[pythonz]`. It gives me this error: `zsh: no matches found: pew[pythonz]`.

Comment: Zsh may treat square brackets specially. Try `pip install "pew[pythonz]"` instead.